# Visual Studio 2008 C# - Can I search for data in dataviewgrid?

Tags: c#, search, datagridview, bindingsource

I've looked all over the web and still can't find anything that works. I know that it's going to be a simple thing that i've just failed to think of but i've wasted hours trying to sort it out and still nothing. So the code I have is below. It just populates a datagridview and then I want the user to be able to search by entering a Contact Name in text box on the form and click the search button. Help would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
    private void frmCustomers_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        sqlDataAdapterCustomers.Fill(dataSetNWCustomers1.Customers);

    }


    private void btnContactSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String contactName = txtContactSearch.Text;

        if (txtContactSearch.TextLength > 0)
        {
            int r = customersBindingSource.Find("ContactName", contactName);
            customersBindingSource.IndexOf(r);

        }


    }
```

Comment: So I understand, you have a DataGridView of contacts that is bound to a SQL data source. When a user enters a search query and clicks submit, you want to filter the DataGridView to only show their search results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`customersBindingSource.Filter = "ContactName ='" + contactName + "'";`

if you already have the data loaded on the binding source. Since the DataGridView is bounded to the binding source, it will update itself to show only the contact searched.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! Exactly what I needed! You wouldn't believe the amount of time I spent on that and not I realise that it was so simple. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteNonQuery` is for **non** queries - that is, it's for statements which do not return a resultset.

Since you appear to be using a strongly-typed dataset, just right-click your table and choose Add->Query. Specify to use SQL Statements, then "SELECT which returns rows", then enter `SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE ContactName = @ContactName` and click "Next". Specify one or both methods, and give them better names (FillByContactName, GetCustomerByContactName). Then click "Finish".

This will generate a method "GetCustomerByContactName(contactName)" which will return a DataTable with the matching customers (if any). You can use this to bind to whichever controls you like.